# How to set cookie to next js application from separate server?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've ne**X**t.js application and i'm sending all requests to my ne**S**t.js server but when i try auth cookie don't save in my browser.

My request to server:

```js
export async function login(data) {
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  const response = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/auth/sign-in`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers,
    body: new URLSearchParams({ ...data, username: data.email })
  });

  if (response.ok) {
    return {
      access_token: await response.json()
    };
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

controller:

```js
@UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)
  @Post("sign-in")
  async login(@Req() req: IReq, @Res() res: Response<string>): Promise<void> {
    const tokens = await this.authService.createTokens(req.user);
    
    res.cookie("refresh_token", tokens.refresh_token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
      signed: true
    });

    res.json(tokens.access_token).status(201);
  }
```

If i make a request with postman, i have cookie.

What other code do I need to provide? Do you need a minimal working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch doesn't save cookies by default. you should use `credentials: 'same-origin'` option in order to save cookies.

```
  const response = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/auth/sign-in`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers,
    credentials: 'same-origin', // <- add this to store cookies
    body: new URLSearchParams({ ...data, username: data.email })
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me a lot. I completely forgot about this option =)

Comment: @Izzei- No problem, first time it took me a whole day for me to debug it (it was in a big real project, and i didn't know where is the bug at all. ). happy coding :)

Comment: Good luck to you)